# How to make Putty the default Telnet handler for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, putty, telnet

I need to use Putty as my Telnet handler client in my ESXi lab. I tried every possible solution that I could find. But nothing worked.

Is there any command I could use in the Registry to force Windows 10 to use Putty instead of the default Telnet client?

Comment: It seems You need to modify `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\telnet\shell\open\command`

Comment: OK. I know that. But how to do that ? I tried to do it few times, but it didn't work. Could you please be more specific on how to do it ?

Comment: Change the default value of this section and set it as `"X:\Folder\Putty.EXE" "%1"`, where `X:\Folder` is the drive letter and folders path to Your telnet client. Or simply go to Associations tab of Control Panel and change the association of telnet protocol (not file type!) to Your prog.

Comment: In the : "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\telnet\shell\open\command", the value date is.............. : ""C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\url.dll",TelnetProtocolHandler %l" ... You want me to change the value inside it to the path of my Putty client ?

Comment: Yes. And don't forget to store somewhere (for example, create BACKUP key in this section and save this value in it) original value. Additionally check PuTTY user manual for its command line switches - maybe You need to add some keys/commands to the command line You will write instead the original one.

Comment: It worked ! I saved the original "value data"  in a text file as backup as you suggested. Thank you very much for your help, sir. большое спасибо :)

Comment: @Akina - would it not be better if you answered in the answer section rather than as a comment ?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\putty.exe" "%1"
```

Thanks @Akina

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).