# Link/protocol handler for telnet on Windows 11

Tags: putty, windows-11, microsoft-edge, telnet

The following configuration to open a telnet:// address does not work on Windows 11 . It was working on Windows 10 though

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\telnet\shell\open\command

Comment: example https://superuser.com/questions/1328558/how-to-make-putty-the-default-telnet-handler-for-windows-10

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Could you add more details?

Comment: when trying to open/click a telnet:// link through a browser, this event does not trigger the opening of the default app for these links. Telnet is also not available in the Settings -> Apps -> Default apps -> Choose defaults by link type